# Duplicate primary Key database entry mysql error for .netcore app

Tags: .net

I am new in web applications level coding. I have been working of an E-commerce sort of project. The challenge I have had is adding products to carts then saving the changes to database. I keep getting the duplicate primary key entry error. My first approach was to save selected products by user to session for unique user experience through serialization of the complex type. I then tried adding the saving and cart methods to my models but I still get the same error. Is there a way I should design my context so there are no duplicates, or my models are wrong? Kindly help.

Here is part of my code:
Models:

```cs
{
    public class User: IdentityUser
    {
        public string Name {get; set;}
        public DateTime CreatedAt {get; set;}
        [NotMapped]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password {get; set;}

    }
     public class ShippingInformation
    {
        [Key]
        public string ShippingInformationId {get; set;}
        public string FirstName {get; set;}
        public string LastName {get; set;}
        public string Address {get; set;}
        public string Address2 {get; set;}
        public string City {get; set;}
        public string ZipCode {get; set;}
        public string State {get; set;}
    }

    public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        public int ProductId {get; set;}
        public int InitialQuantity {get; set;}
        public int Price {get; set;}
        public string Title {get; set;}
        public string Image {get; set;}
        public string Description {get; set;}

        [NotMapped]
        public int Quantity {get; set;}
    }
    public class CartItem
    {

        [Key]
        public int CartItemId {get; set;}
        public string UserId {get; set;}
        [ForeignKey("Product")]
        public string ShoppingCartId {get; set;}
        public User customer {get; set;}
        public Product product {get; set;}
        public string FirstName {get; set;}
        public string LastName {get; set;}
        public string Address {get; set;}
        public string Address2 {get; set;}
        public string City {get; set;}
        public string ZipCode {get; set;}
        public string State {get; set;}
        public int Quantity {get; set;}

    }
    public class ShoppingCart
    {
        private MyContext _dbcontext;
        public ShoppingCart(MyContext mycontext)
        {
            _dbcontext=mycontext;

        }
        public string ShoppingCartId {get; set; }
        public List<CartItem> MyCart {get; set;}
        public ShoppingCart GetCart(HttpContext services)
          {

            ISession session=services.Session;
            string cartid=session.GetString("CartId")??Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            session.SetString("CartId", cartid);

            return  new ShoppingCart(_dbcontext){ShoppingCartId=cartid};
        }
        public ShoppingCart GetCart(Controller controller)
        {
            return GetCart(controller.HttpContext);
        }
public void AddToCart(Product product, int quantity)
        {

            var cartitem=_dbcontext.cartitems
            .FirstOrDefault(n=>n.product.ProductId==product.ProductId && n.ShoppingCartId==ShoppingCartId);
            if (cartitem==null)
            {
                cartitem=new CartItem
                {ShoppingCartId=ShoppingCartId, product=product, Quantity=1};
                _dbcontext.cartitems.Add(cartitem);
            }

            else
            {
                cartitem.Quantity++;
            }
            _dbcontext.SaveChanges();

        }

        public List<CartItem> GetCartItems()
        {
            var ShoppingCartItems=
            _dbcontext.cartitems.Include(y=>y.product).
            Where(d=>d.ShoppingCartId==ShoppingCartId).ToList();
            return ShoppingCartItems;

        }
    }


        public class OrderItem
    {
        public int Order  {get; set;}
        public string Customer {get; set;}
        public string Item {get; set;}
        public string Product {get; set;}
    }
```

Controller:

```cs
{
    public class ShoppingCartController: Controller
    {
        private readonly MyContext dbcontext;
        private readonly ShoppingCart mycart;
        public ShoppingCartController(MyContext context, ShoppingCart shoppingCart)
        {
            dbcontext=context;
            mycart=shoppingCart;
        }
        [Route("Index")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {

            var items=mycart.GetCartItems();

            return View(items);
        }
        [Route("addtocart")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AddToCart(Product n)
        {
            var cart= mycart.GetCart(this);
            cart.AddToCart(n, n.Quantity);
            return RedirectToAction("Checkout");
        }
        [Authorize]  
        [Route("checkout")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Checkout()
        {
            ViewBag.purchases=mycart.GetCartItems();
            return View();
        }
```

Startup:

```
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseMySql(Configuration["DBInfo:ConnectionString"]));
            services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            services.Configure<StripeSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("Stripe"));
            services.AddScoped<HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddSingleton<HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession();            
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddAuthentication();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            StripeConfiguration.SetApiKey(Configuration.GetSection("Stripe")["SecretKey"]);
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseSession();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            //InitializeRoles(app.ApplicationServices).Wait();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was actually very simple. So after trying to modify my models and relationships with no success, the relationship I had set for the products (orders, and other tables) was such that an already existing product item added in cart will again get created when I enter new order into database with "dbcontext.orders.add……." method. Entity framework will still try to enter new record for the product table in the relationship. I corrected this by using the update method instead: "dbcontext.orders.update….."